# Diophantine equation and Turing Machine

Tags: diophantine-equations, computability

If a Diophantine equation is: exists v, p(x,v) = 0 (where v is a vector of finitely many integers) for some polynomial p, is there a Turing machine which prints out all values of x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a polynomial $p(\bar{x},\bar{v})$ with integer coefficients, there is indeed a Turing machine that enumerates all tuples of integers $\bar{x}$ for which there exists a tuple of integers $\bar{v}$ with $p(\bar{x},\bar{v}) = 0$. In other words, the set of such tuples $\bar{x}$ is recursively enumerable.

One way to do the enumeration is to start by making a machine that enumerates *all* pairs of integer tuples $(\bar{x}, \bar{v})$ (where each tuple has the appropriate length). Then feed the output of this machine into a machine that checks whether $p(\bar{x},\bar{v}) = 0$.

On the other hand, there is no Turing machine that takes a polynomial $p$ as input, and a tuple $\bar{x}$ as a second input, and decides whether there is a tuple $\bar{v}$ of integers with $p(\bar{x},\bar{v}) = 0$. This is the MRDP theorem, which solved [Hilbert's 10th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem).

Comment: ah thank you, it's possible to print them all out but not in order.